# Divide byte into two smaller numbers

Tags: java, byte

Like in topic. I am writing application where I must save as much RAM as possible. I want to split byte into two parts 4 bits each (numbers from 0 to 15) - how can I save and later read this values?

Comment: I don't think you can have a nibble in Java? But you might need bitwise &, | to set and/or read the bits

Comment: Since numbers in Java are signed, when using 4 bits you will probably end up with numbers from `-8` to `7`, unless you do some maths yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain how splitting a byte in 2 nibbles is going to help you save memory space?

Comment: @VisruthCV convert to binary? All data is already in binary form when in a computer. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @afsantos No since there's no nibble data type.

Comment: Do you mean to store 2 numbers in one byte?

Comment: How exactly it is going to save any RAM?

Comment: 1 byte is taking less space than 2 bytes - I need to store a lot of very small numbers and read them rarely.

Comment: @VisruthCV sorry that's pure nonsense. 12 is already stored as 1100 by the computer. A computer only knows binary. You are confusing the representation of a number with its value.

Comment: @VisruthCV Sorry but a `boolean` in Java most likely does not take 1 bit. This JVM implementation-dependent but even if it sounds counter-intuitive using 1 bit might be slower than using a byte. This is due to the fact that smallest unit used by a CPU for a programmer is byte and not bit. Also an array is an object in Java so it will take even more space.

Comment: Learn about shift and mask operations -- `<<, >>, &, |`.  It's a little clumsy at times, but basically very simple to combine several n-bit values into a byte or int, and not particularly inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, `boolean` values occupy at least a byte in most implementations.  In some they may actually occupy a 4-byte word when in the stack or in an instance field, though generally only 8 bits in an array.  For the JVM I worked on we considered doing 1-bit arrays, but it was too messy for too little benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is store 2 numbers (range 0-15) in one byte, here's an example on how to save and restore them. Note that you have to make sure your original numbers are within the allowed range, otherwise this will not work.

```
    // Store both numbers in one byte
    byte firstNumber = 10;
    byte secondNumber = 15;
    final byte bothNumbers = (byte) ((firstNumber << 4) | secondNumber);

    // Retreive the original numbers
    firstNumber = (byte) ((bothNumbers >> 4) & (byte) 0x0F);
    secondNumber = (byte) (bothNumbers & 0x0F);
```

Also worth noting that **if you want to save as much memory as possible you shouldn't be using Java** to start with. JVM already consumes memory by itself. Native languages are much more suited to this requirement.

Comment: Fixed required casts and masking.

Answer (score 3):

You can get lower bits as

```
byte lower = b & 0xF;
```

higher bits as

```
byte higher = (b >> 4) & 0xF;
```

and back to one byte

```
byte b  = (byte) (lower + (higher << 4));
```

Comment: Almost working - it seems that b >> 3 is giving correct values - now how to save values into one byte?

Comment: `&`is missing, and please use `|` instead of addition for combining bit fields.